# Does HDCP impose HD-playback restrictions for sinks?

Tags: compliance, drm

In order to be HDCP compliant, a source can only output HDCP-encrypted digital HD content.

However, is the opposite true for HDCP sinks? In order to be HDCP compliant, should a sink only accept to reproduce digital HD content when it's HDCP-encrypted?